# Projecting a grayscale 2D numpy image into RGB?

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, scikit-image

I have a grayscale numpy image (`shape=(1024, 1024, 1)`, `dtype=float`) that I'm trying to translate into the same image, but with the grayscale values assigned to the red channel (ie. the same image but in redscale).

Here's the original image:

[image: original grayscale image]

Which is generated using numpy:

```
def create_mandelbrot_matrix(width, height, max_iter=100):
    X = np.linspace(-2, 1, width)
    Y = np.linspace(-1, 1, height)
    
    #broadcast X to a square array
    C = X[:, None] + 1J * Y
    #initial value is always zero
    Z = np.zeros_like(C)

    exit_times = max_iter * np.ones(C.shape, np.int32)
    mask = exit_times > 0

    for k in range(max_iter):
        Z[mask] = Z[mask] * Z[mask] + C[mask]
        mask, old_mask = abs(Z) < 2, mask
        #use XOR to detect the area which has changed 
        exit_times[mask ^ old_mask] = k
    
    return exit_times.T

def mandelbrot_image(width, height, max_iter=100):
    mandelbrot_matrix = create_mandelbrot_matrix(width, height, max_iter)
    img = np.expand_dims(mandelbrot_matrix, axis=2)
    return img
```

This function results in a totally different image from the original:

```
def mandelbrot_red_image(w, h):
    mandelbrot_img = mandelbrot_image(w, h)
    print(mandelbrot_img.shape) # (1024, 1024, 1)
    img = np.zeros((w, h, 3))
    img[:, :, 0] = mandelbrot_img_int.reshape((w, h))
    return img
```

[image: problem redscale image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont know how your mandelbrot_image works, but image shapes are usually (h, w), due to the number of lines in a matrix being the first dimension, and the height.

Another point is that, maybe your dtype is not 'uint8', I had to do a conversion in order to the image appear properly.

This code worked for me

```
from cv2 import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('./mandelbrot.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
h, w = img.shape
color_img = np.zeros([h, w, 3])
color_img[:, :, 2] = img  # In opencv images are BGR

cv2.imshow('color_mandelbrot', color_img.astype('uint8'))
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Just noticed that your image is square, so the order does not matter much, but it's a good point to pay attention to.

Comment: My issue was using a uint8 array as a float array. I was able to convert it with `np.float32`, then transformed the color space from 0..255 to 0..1 using `mandelbrot_gray_flt = mandelbrot_gray / 255`.